# python2 to 3 use of list()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm converting python2.7 scripts to python3.
`2to3` makes these kinds of suggestions:

```
         result        = result.split(',')
         syslog_trace("Result   : {0}".format(result), False, DEBUG)

-        data.append(map(float, result))
+        data.append(list(map(float, result)))
         if (len(data) > samples):
           data.pop(0)
         syslog_trace("Data     : {0}".format(data),   False, DEBUG)

         # report sample average
         if (startTime % reportTime < sampleTime):
-          somma       = map(sum, zip(*data))
+          somma       = list(map(sum, list(zip(*data))))
           # not all entries should be float
           # 0.37, 0.18, 0.17, 4, 143, 32147, 3, 4, 93, 0, 0
           averages    = [format(sm / len(data), '.3f') for sm in somma]
```

I'm sure the makers of Python3 did not want to do it like that. At least, it gives me a "you must be kidding" feeling.

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: List comprehension, maybe.  `[float(x) for x in result]`

Comment: @zondo : thanks. I'll investigate list comprehension.  Does that also work for the `map(sum, zip(*data))`?

Comment: Yes.  Use `[sum(d) for d in zip(*data)]`

Comment: That's the *"quick fix"* mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), which also suggests using list comps instead.

Comment: `2to3` is intended to translate Python 2 code into *equivalent* Python 3 code. The next step is to make it *well-written* Python 3, but an automatic tool won't do it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with the unfixed `somma`?

`2to3` cannot know how `somma` is going to be used, in that case, as a generator in the next line to compute `averages` it is OK and optimal, no need to convert it as a list.

That's the genius of python 3 list to generator changes: most people used those lists as generators already, wasting precious memory materializing lists they did not need.

```
     # report sample average
     if (startTime % reportTime < sampleTime):
      somma       = map(sum, zip(*data))
       # not all entries should be float
       # 0.37, 0.18, 0.17, 4, 143, 32147, 3, 4, 93, 0, 0
       averages    = [format(sm / len(data), '.3f') for sm in somma]
```

Of course the first statement, unconverted, will fail since we append a generator whereas we need a list. In that case, the error is quickly fixed.

If left like this: `data.append(map(float, result))`, the next trace shows something fishy: `'Data     : [<map object at 0x00000000043DB6A0>]'`, that you can quickly fix by cnverting to `list` as `2to3` suggested.

`2to3` does its best to create running Python 3 code, but it does not replace manual rework or produce optimal code. When you are in a hurry you can apply it, but always check the diffs vs the old code like the OP did.

The `-3` option of latest Python 2 versions print warnings when an error would be raised using Python 3. It's another approach, better when you have more time to perform your migration.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sure the makers of Python3 did not want to do it like that

Well, the makers of Python generally don't like seeing Python 2 being used, I've seen that sentiment being expressed in pretty much every recent PyCon.

> Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

That really depends on your interpretation of Pythonic, list comps seem more intuitive in your case, you **want** to construct a `list` so there's no need to create an iterator with `map` or `zip` and **then** feed it to `list()`.

Now, why `2to3` chose `list()` wrapping instead of comps, I do not know; probably easiest to actually implement.